# ReferenceError: firebase is not defined in firebase with nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to access the email and uid of current signed in user but this error is shown

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
    const admin = require('firebase-admin');
    admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
const firestore= admin.firestore();
    exports.StripeSource =functions.firestore.document('cards/{data}/tokens/{tokenid}').onCreate(async (tokenSnap,context) => {
      var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    var name, email, photoUrl, uid, emailVerified;
      email = user.email;
      uid = user.uid; 
    console.log('User Email is :', email);

      });
```

**Error in fire base log**

```
ReferenceError: firebase is not defined
    at exports.StripeSource.functions.firestore.document.onCreate (/srv/index.js:8:14)
    at cloudFunction (/srv/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:131:23)
    at /worker/worker.js:825:24
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:229:7)
```

but changing `firebase.auth().currentUser;` to `admin.auth().currentUser;` it works perfectly but recieved error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'email' of undefined
    at exports.StripeSource.functions.firestore.document.onCreate (/srv/index.js:8:16)
    at cloudFunction (/srv/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:131:23)
    at /worker/worker.js:825:24
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:229:7)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this:

```
  var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
```

into this:

```
  var user = admin.auth().currentUser;
```

Check here for more information:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth

Comment: super awesome sir but I have another issue I just update the question please check it

Comment: check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50235846/admin-auth-currentuser-returning-undefined-in-cloud-function you cannot get the current user in cloud functions, also check this link for the methods https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth

Comment: Thanks peter. 
is there any way to access document name set according to user name?  I can access a static document name in node js but if I set document name which is different for each user(may be according to name or email address) is there anyway access variable document name in nodejs?

Comment: you mean document id in firestore?

Comment: yes. 
 I can share the code for your better understanding

Comment: Please ask another question as this is not related to this question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203967/discussion-between-developer-and-peter-haddad).